# What will be the minimum drift possible when a boat crosses a river?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, velocity, relative-motion

Imagine a boat with a constant speed $v$ that has to cross a river of width $d$. Let the river flow with a constant velocity $u$. I want to know the angle at which the boat should sail in order to land closest to the point opposite to the starting point.

[image]

I know that drift can be zero it the boat travells at an angle such that $v \sin(x)=u$ but this is only possible when $v>u$.

How can I calculate minimum drift and corresponding angle when $u>v$?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time taken to cross the river is

$\displaystyle t = \frac d {v \cos(x)}$

In this time, the downstream drift $D$ will be

$D = (u - v \sin(x)) t
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow D = \frac d v \left( \frac u {\cos(x)} - v \tan(x) \right)
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {dD}{dx} = \frac d v \left( \frac {u \sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)} - \frac v {\cos^2(x)} \right)$

Setting $\frac {dD}{dx}$ to zero, we see that $D$ is minimised when

$\displaystyle \sin(x) = \frac v u$

Comment: Why this derivation do not require any use of $u>v$

Comment: @SharanyaSingh $u>v$ is required so that $D>0$ for all values of $x$. If $u<v$ then $D$ can be negative, so we want to minimise $|D|$ rather than just $D$, and we can do this by setting $sin(x) = \frac u v$, when $D=0$.

Comment: @gandalf61 the final value is obtained when you assume $\cos x\ne0$. What happens when $\cos x=0$,i.e., $x=\pi/2$? Intuitively it makes sense since the entire velocity is used to counter the river speed, but this also means that the boat will never reach the other end. So how about the limiting case($x\to\pi/2$)? I couldn't understand why this isn't valid. Note that it would take an infinite amount of time to reach the other end.

Answer (score 1):

First break the $V$ into two components
[image: 1]

The drift $D$ can be written as

$$(u-v\sin x)t=D$$

to find minimum $D$, we differentiate and then equate to $0$
$$\frac{\text{d}D}{\text{d}t}=0 \\ ut-v\sin(x)t=D$$

Differentiating both sides,
$$\left(t\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}t}+u\frac{\text{d}t}{\text{d}t}\right)-\left(\frac{\text{d}(v\sin x)}{\text{d}t}+v\sin x\frac{\text{d}t}{\text{d}t}\right)=0 \\ \left(t\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}t}+u\frac{\text{d}t}{\text{d}t}\right)-\left(v\frac{\text{d}(\sin x)}{\text{d}t}+\sin(x)\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}+v\sin x\frac{\text{d}t}{\text{d}t}\right)=0$$

We know,
$$\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}=0$$
and
$$\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}t}=0$$
since acceleration is $0$. So we can write the equation as
$$(0+u)-\left(v\frac{\text{d}(\sin x)}{\text{d}t}+0+v\sin x\right)=0 \\ u-(-v\cos x+v\sin x)=0 \\ u+v\cos x-v\sin x=0 \\ v=\frac{u}{\sin x-\cos x}$$

If we have the velocity of the boat and the velocity of the river, then we can find the angle for which drift is minimum for that particular velocity of boat using the above relation.

Comment: $\frac {d\sin(x)}{dt}$ is not $\cos(x)$, it is $\cos(x)\frac {dx}{dt}$

Comment: Oh my bad. Also thanks for not straight up downvoting my answer and letting me know. Appreciate the help

Comment: I don’t know how to proceed, with my solution now. Can you please edit mine or tell me how to solve with this method?